System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException when setting RadioButton IsChecked in MAUI
I am making a property app where I have one file for LandingPage.cs and another for LandingViewModel.cs. The goal is to bind a list of sections to radio buttons and set the first radio button as checked. However, I encounter an error when trying to set the first radio button as checked. Here is my code:
// LandingViewModel.cs
using PropertyApp.Model;
using PropertyApp.View;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace PropertyApp.ViewModel
{
    public class LandingViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        public List<string> Sections = new List<string> { "Trending", "Popular", "Buy", "Rent" };

        public List<Property> Properties => PropertyRepo.AllProperties;

        public Property SelectedProperty { get; set; }

        public ICommand PropertySelected => new Command(obj =>
        {
            if (SelectedProperty != null)
                Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new DetailsPage(SelectedProperty));
            SelectedProperty = null;
        });
    }
}


// LandingPage.cs
using PropertyApp.ViewModel;

namespace PropertyApp.View
{
    public partial class LandingPage : ContentPage
    {
        public LandingPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.BindingContext = new LandingViewModel();
            (SectionList.Children[0] as RadioButton).IsChecked = true;
        }
    }
}


using this line
(SectionList.Children[0] as RadioButton).IsChecked = true;
Got this error
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. (Parameter 'index')
Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong? I want to activate the radio buttons for the list of sections given, but in the Android emulator, the buttons are not showing.

The error message is pretty clear, SectionList.Children is an array with no elements. We'd need to see how your view looks like to help with why it's empty.

In Android emulator the list of string which I have provided in LandingViewModel.cs are showing and the radio buttons are not showing up.

Your xaml describing your view is missing, the issue is probably related to it

Unlike your Properties object, your SectionList is not updating the value sent to the UI
So this line
public List<string> Sections = new List<string> { "Trending", "Popular", "Buy", "Rent" };

should be
public List<string> Sections => new List<string> { "Trending", "Popular", "Buy", "Rent" };

